# list of name and path of files in a directory and subdirectory where one or more subdir have a point in the middle python

Tags: python, glob

I'm trying to get path and filename, from a directory, including those ones inside the subdirectories. The problem is that some subfolders have one or more points in the name. 
So when I execute this code

```
listaFile=glob.glob('c:\test\ID_1'+/**/*.*',recursive= True)
```

I get
c:\test\ID_1\fil.e1.txt 
c:\test\ID_1\fil.e2.doc
c:\test\ID_1\subfolder1\file1.txt
**c:\test\ID_1\sub.folder2** (instead of c:\test\ID_1\sub.folder2\file1.txt)
thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter it out checking if it's a file or folder. An easy way would be to use the pathlib instead of glob directly. Example below.

```
listaFile = [str(path) for path in pathlib.Path(r"c:\test\ID_1").rglob("*.*") if path.is_file()]
```

Comment: it works! but how can I get a list of strings instead of WindowsPath objects?

Comment: just use a str() to make it a string ! ?

Comment: easier then I thought :)